# Why am I receiving a javafx.fxml.LoadException when loading my FXML file?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm using Java JDK 13, and FontAwesomeFX 11.

I have a FXML file which contains some FontAwesomeIconViews, but when loading the file into my controller I'm getting a javafx.fxml.LoadException. This is how the FXML file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<VBox id="window" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <BorderPane id="upper" fx:id="upper" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="800.0" stylesheets="@style.css">
         <left>
            <Label text="TEXT" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <font>
                  <Font size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </left>
         <right>
            <HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
LINE 27           <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="WINDOW_MINIMIZE" size="20" />
                  <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="CLOSE" size="30" />
               </children></HBox>
         </right>
      </BorderPane>
      <AnchorPane id="body" prefHeight="554.0" prefWidth="800.0">
         <children>
            <TextField layoutX="326.0" layoutY="233.0" promptText="Usuario" />


<PasswordField layoutX="326.0" layoutY="276.0" promptText="Contraseña" />
        <Button layoutX="353.0" layoutY="334.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="94.0" text="Acceder" />
        <Label layoutX="326.0" layoutY="372.0" text="¿Ha olvidado la contraseña?" />
        <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="USER_CIRCLE" layoutX="350.0" layoutY="185.0" size="100" />
     </children>
  </AnchorPane>
</children>
</VBox>
</children>
</VBox>
```

I'm getting the error on the first FontAwesomeIconView element (WINDOW_MINIMIZE).

I have suspicions it could be because FontAwesomeFX 11 expects FontAwesomeIconViews to be formatted in another way, but I'm not sure at all.

```
Error al cargar el archivo vista Login.fxml: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
.../bin/view/login.fxml:27

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Root cannot be null
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:345)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:236)
    at controller.SplashController$SplashScreen$2.run(SplashController.java:78)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
```

Comment: The BorderPane.alignment static property only makes sense for nodes whose parent is a BorderPane. Is it your case ?

Comment: @pacataque Yes, it is.

Comment: @pacataque I edited with the whole FXML file.

Comment: Thank you !
Try to put your  <FontAwesomeIconView> inside <graphic> bracket

Comment: @pacataque Not working

Comment: You have to post the whole stacktrace, that will show more information. The FXML is correct, but your project might have the wrong dependencies.

Comment: @JoséPereda Posted! The problem is loader.load() throws LoadException and then I get a NullPointerException because of that null value.

Comment: You have to close <children> and <VBox>

Comment: @pacataque I didn't copy it right, sorry. They where there all the time.

Comment: Are you using Gradle or Maven?

Comment: @JoséPereda I don't know to be honest. I'm using Eclipse...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever you get a `javafx.fxml.LoadException`, you have to read the whole stacktrace until the very end. It will show, usually at the end, the real *cause* for the exception.

Let's say you have this `build.gradle` file, and your project is non-modular:

```
plugins {
  id 'application'
  id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "de.jensd:fontawesomefx-commons:11.0"
    implementation "de.jensd:fontawesomefx-fontawesome:4.7.0-11"
}

mainClassName = 'org.openjfx.MainApp'

javafx {
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}
```

and the FXML file with `FontAwesomeIconView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="org.openjfx.FXMLController">
      <FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="WINDOW_MINIMIZE" size="20" />
</VBox>
```

Then you run the project:

```
./gradlew clean run
```

and you get:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 ...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/.../build/resources/main/org/openjfx/scene.fxml:7
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2603)
```

If you stop reading there, you will think something is wrong with the line `scene.fxml:7` which is the `FontAwesomeIconView` one.

But if you keep reading the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 ...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/.../build/resources/main/org/openjfx/scene.fxml:7
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2603)

...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.put(BeanAdapter.java:262)
...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: \
    Unable to make javafx.css.ParsedValue javafx.css.CssParser.parseExpr(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) accessible: \
    module javafx.graphics does not "opens javafx.css" to unnamed module @32ab3e54
    ...
     at de.jensd.fx.glyphs.GlyphIcon.convert(GlyphIcon.java:248)
...
```

that last `Caused by` says exactly the reason of the problem:

> module javafx.graphics does not "opens javafx.css" to unnamed module @32ab3e54

This is due to the use of reflection in `GlyphIcon` to access private API.

So now that you know the reason, all you have to do is provide the solution: In this case, we will add the requested `--add-opens` to the jvm args in the build.gradle file:

```
run {
    jvmArgs = ["--add-opens", "javafx.graphics/javafx.css=ALL-UNNAMED"]
}
```

Running again it will work.

*Note 1*

If you have a modular project, with a module-info descriptor like:

```
module hellofx {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires de.jensd.fx.fontawesomefx.fontawesome;

    opens org.openjfx to javafx.fxml;
    exports org.openjfx;
}
```

then you have to add instead:

```
run {
    jvmArgs = ["--add-opens", "javafx.graphics/javafx.css=de.jensd.fx.fontawesomefx.commons"]
}
```

*Note 2*

If you are not using Gradle, you can still do the same.

For starters check the guide JavaFX 13 with Eclipse: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse, and then choose your case.

If your case is non-modular from IDE, when you set the VM arguments like:

```
--module-path /path/to/javafx-sdk-13/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

all you need to do now is include the extra argument, like:

```
--module-path /path/to/javafx-sdk-13/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml \
--add-opens javafx.graphics/javafx.css=ALL-UNNAMED
```

For other cases, the logic is the same.